# Como obtener # en cierto Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Tengo un regex para hacer match de un archivo que pueden contener hexadecimales decimales(con exponentes) y palabras

> `(0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+)|([0-9]+[\.][0-9]*[eE]?[+]?[0-9]*)|([0-9]+)|(\w{0,31})|.)`

Mi problema es que con las palabras desearía que me hiciera match con, por ejemplo, #Palabra, incluyendo el #, de manera que quedara el # y palabra en distintos matches, mi problema es que no le hace match incluso si le pongo "."

Digamos que tengo "#define PROCEDURE void"
Lo que obtengo en mis matches son

- ""
- "define"
- ""
- "PROCEDURE"
- ""
- "void"

Y lo que desearia obtener es

- "#define"
- ""
- "PROCEDURE"
- ""
- "void"

Comment: por favor añade un par de ejemplos de tus string y el resultado deseado

Comment: Listo añadi una cadena simple y mi resultado esperado